# Manipulating date in column of a dataframe

Tags: r, date, time, dplyr, lubridate

Update the column of `dataframe` with the date which is greater than today by deducting 1 year from that date

```
f1 %>% filter(Fresh.email.date > today()) %>% ymd(list(Fresh.email.date)) - years(1)
```

Comment: I think after the `today())` step, you need to `pull(Fresh.email.date)` based on the code showed.  `%>% pulll(Fresh.email.date) %>% ymd(.)  %>% magrittr::subtract(years(1))`

Comment: I need to update the dates in the Fresh.email.date which are greater than sysdate or today, by subtracting one year from the same.

Comment: Do you want to update in the original dataset or the `filter`ed one

Comment: Original one. column name Fresh.email.date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We dont' need to `filter` if the intention is the update the original column.  Using `case_when`, we create a logical condition and substract one year when the date is greater than `today()` or else return the date

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(Fresh.email.date = ymd(Fresh.email.date), 
         Fresh.email.date = case_when(Fresh.email.date > today() ~ 
                            Fresh.email.date - years(1), 
       TRUE ~ Fresh.email.date))
```